# Spelling aquaeductus together

Tags: classical-latin, spelling

The word *aquaeductus* can also be spelled *aquae ductus* or *ductus aquae*, possibly with the plural *aquarum* (see [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=aquaeductus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)).
Spelling it separately in either order makes sense, as the aqueduct is a conductor (*ductus*) of water (*aquae*).
But why is it also spelled together in classical Latin?

To be more precise, is there classical evidence for spelling *aqueductus* as a single word?
If yes, what does that even mean?
Word boundaries were not as clearly defined and marked as today, but they were not entirely non-existent either.
Perhaps this is just a later editorial decision and has nothing to do with classical spelling, but it's hard for me to judge.

Answer (score 2):

The "slam dunk" evidence we'd want in a case like this is an inscription with word boundaries that does not separate *aquaeductus*.

Though I can't find any such evidence after a brief search, one piece of indirect evidence makes the supposition likely, especially given the fact that scholars much smarter than me have adopted the convention of spelling it as a compound. This indirect evidence is that the word is likely an imitation of the Greek equivalents: [*ὑδραγωγία*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Du(dragw%2Fgion) or [*ὑδραγώγιον*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Du(dragw%2Fgion).

Here, unlike in Latin, the compounding behavior is much more evident. Latin wasn't quite as productive as Greek with compounds of this kind, but it certainly seems to be a point in favor!

Comment: Stress patterns within the word might also give us a clue.